# Can I downgrade a VS15 Enterprise trial with a Professional key?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Title says it all, I installed the VS15 Enterprise trial and signed in with my account to get a 90 day trial.
Now it's coming to the end and I put the Professional key in thinking it may downgrade functionality, as a colleague has told me he is pretty certain he did the same thing.

It's not working so I was just wondering if anyone can confirm whether I have to re-install VS15 (but the professional version)?

Comment: I do believe that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add that it is actually possible. Please check Adam's answer on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515725/any-quick-ways-to-downgrade-visual-studio-ultimate-enterprise-edition-to-profess):

> If you had previously installed VS Pro, as I had, you might be able to go to "Add/Remove Programs" and select "Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise with Updates." Modify->Uninstall worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just for those who may end up here, in the end I personally re-installed Professional as it just wasn't playing ball - but am not sure if there's some other magic that could have been done.